# Using Lagged Values Conditionally in R

Tags: r, loops

What I want to do is take the split_coefficient value in the rows with the split_coefficient !=1 to be used in calculations with the adjusted_close for the prior dates in the data frame.  I'm trying to create a loop in R that will multiple the adjusted_close values by the split_coefficient up to but not including the row which contains split_coefficient that != 1 and repeat the process to the end of the data set. I am able to identify those rows with split_coefficients != 1 using `which(y[,6] !=1`, but cannot figure out how to write the loops to accomplish this task. Any help on how to create this loop would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

```
timestamp   open    high    low close   adjusted_close  split_coefficient
7/20/2018   31.61   31.72   30.95   31.04   31.04   1
7/19/2018   31.17   31.57   30.69   31.19   31.19   1
7/18/2018   30.53   31.33   30.26   30.63   30.63   1
7/17/2018   31.67   31.825  30.49   30.89   30.89   1
7/16/2018   31.24   31.79   31  31.23   31.23   1
7/13/2018   32.06   32.37   31.36   31.45   31.45   1
7/12/2018   32.29   32.68   31.69   31.69   31.69   1
7/11/2018   33.37   33.47   32.43   32.93   32.93   1
7/10/2018   32.19   32.8185 31.75   31.84   31.84   1
7/9/2018    33.32   33.37   32.249  32.48   32.48   0.25
7/6/2018    36.03   36.17   34.15   34.23   34.23   1
7/5/2018    36.47   37.46   36.05   36.09   36.09   1
7/3/2018    36.28   37.8299 36  37.33   37.33   1
7/2/2018    38.74   39.22   37.03   37.08   37.08   1
6/29/2018   36.71   37.06   35.78   37  37  1
6/28/2018   38.88   40.51   37.46   38.03   38.03   0.35
6/27/2018   36.14   39.43   35.21   38.56   38.56   1
6/26/2018   36.54   37.89   35.715  36.48   36.48   1
6/25/2018   34.24   39.745  34.24   38.11   38.11   1
6/22/2018   33.04   33.57   32.72   33.06   33.06   1
6/21/2018   32.26   34.84   32.21   34.15   34.15   1
6/20/2018   32.13   32.21   31.655  32.02   32.02   0.5
6/19/2018   33.33   33.92   32.43   32.79   32.79   1
6/18/2018   32.55   33.02   31.19   31.24   31.24   1
6/15/2018   31.94   32.52   31.52   31.67   31.67   1
6/14/2018   31.5    31.83   30.91   31.33   31.33   1
6/13/2018   31.58   32.45   31.44   32.39   32.39   1
6/12/2018   31.86   32.41   31.66   31.97   31.97   1
6/11/2018   32.67   32.77   31.91   32.09   32.09   1
6/8/2018    33.46   33.56   32.41   32.6    32.6    1
```

I'll try to clarify my question:
On 6/20/18, the split coefficient is .50.  What I want to do is multiple the split_coefficient of .5 by the adjusted_close values from 6/8/18 to 6/19/18. The split_coefficient then changes to .35 on 6/28/18 where I want to multiple the Adjusted_close from 6/21/18 to 6/27/18 by .35.  Since the split_coefficient changes periodically, I thought a loop or series of loops would accomplish this.

Based on what I wrote above, I am looking for the following output with anew column named New.adj.Close which will contain the values calculated when multiplying the split_coefficient from 6/20/18 on the adjusted_close values for 6/8/18 - 6/19/18:

```
timestamp   open    high    low close   adjusted_close  dividend_amount split_coefficient   New.Adj.close
6/19/2018   33.33   33.92   32.43   32.79   32.79   0   1   16.395
6/18/2018   32.55   33.02   31.19   31.24   31.24   0   1   15.62
6/15/2018   31.94   32.52   31.52   31.67   31.67   0   1   15.835
6/14/2018   31.5    31.83   30.91   31.33   31.33   0   1   15.665
6/13/2018   31.58   32.45   31.44   32.39   32.39   0   1   16.195
6/12/2018   31.86   32.41   31.66   31.97   31.97   0   1   15.985
6/11/2018   32.67   32.77   31.91   32.09   32.09   0   1   16.045
6/8/2018    33.46   33.56   32.41   32.6    32.6    0   1   16.3
```

Comment: What are these loops supposed to do? The question is unclear. In any event, 90% of the time in R the right question isn't how to write a loop -- it is how to *avoid* a loop.

Comment: Please make a minimal example, just enough columns and rows to show what you mean and also show what the expected results are.  This might be an ifelse() situation ...

Comment: @Elin I've tried to clarify what I am looking to accomplish and added sample output to show what the desired output would look like.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you actually want the rows with the !=1 split_coefficient to be dropped from the data frame, is that correct?

Comment: @Elin What I actually want to do is take the split_coefficient value in the rows with the split_coefficient !=1 to be used in calculations with the adjusted_close for the prior dates in the data frame.

Comment: You should change you question title to something like "using lagged values conditionally."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this uses the tidyverse but you can recode it to use base r or whatever. The important thing is the logic.
As mentioned you do not normally want to use loops for a task like this, and in this case you would have to do a do while loop.  Instead take advantage of vectorization.

```
measure_date <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 20)
pattern <- c(.5, 1,1,1,1)
split_coefficient <- c(pattern, pattern, pattern, pattern)
value_to_multiply <- c(1:20)

df <- data.frame(measure_date, value_to_multiply, split_coefficient)

# doing this because OP's data is reversed
df <- dplyr::arrange(df, measure_date)

# Change the 1s to NAs.

df$newsplit <- ifelse(df$split_coefficient == 1, NA, df$split_coefficient)

df <- tidyr::fill(df , newsplit)
df$multiplied <- df$value_to_multiply*df$newsplit
df
```

Results

```
   measure_date value_to_multiply split_coefficient newsplit multiplied
1    2000-01-01                 1               0.5      0.5        0.5
2    2000-01-02                 2               1.0      0.5        1.0
3    2000-01-03                 3               1.0      0.5        1.5
4    2000-01-04                 4               1.0      0.5        2.0
5    2000-01-05                 5               1.0      0.5        2.5
6    2000-01-06                 6               0.5      0.5        3.0
7    2000-01-07                 7               1.0      0.5        3.5
8    2000-01-08                 8               1.0      0.5        4.0
9    2000-01-09                 9               1.0      0.5        4.5
10   2000-01-10                10               1.0      0.5        5.0
11   2000-01-11                11               0.5      0.5        5.5
12   2000-01-12                12               1.0      0.5        6.0
13   2000-01-13                13               1.0      0.5        6.5
14   2000-01-14                14               1.0      0.5        7.0
15   2000-01-15                15               1.0      0.5        7.5
16   2000-01-16                16               0.5      0.5        8.0
17   2000-01-17                17               1.0      0.5        8.5
18   2000-01-18                18               1.0      0.5        9.0
19   2000-01-19                19               1.0      0.5        9.5
20   2000-01-20                20               1.0      0.5       10.0
```

Comment: You could definitely make this code shorter, but I think that probably obscures the logic.

Comment: Also I would mention, that what I did here was make a minimal example, doing that would have helped you explain the question better to people trying to help.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who provided a response to my convoluted question and to @Elin for all of the help provided to come up with a solution and help refining my question!

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, do you just want to multiply `adjusted_close` by `split_coefficient` for the observations where `split_coefficient` equals 1? If so,

```
library(dplyr)
y %>% filter(split_coefficient == 1) %>% mutate(new_col = split_coefficient *adjusted_close)
```

Apologies if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: If you are multiplying by 1 what's the point? That's why the question is confusing. Also what happens to the other values are they supposed to be NA?

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted in the comments, using loops in `R` is usually avoided and better alternatives are available. For example you can use `ifelse`:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    adjusted_close = sample(1:5, 10, TRUE),
    split_coefficient = sample(1:2, 10, TRUE)
  )

#    adjusted_close split_coefficient
# 1               5                 1
# 2               2                 2
# 3               3                 2
# 4               2                 2
# 5               4                 2
# 6               5                 2
# 7               1                 1
# 8               2                 1
# 9               2                 2
# 10              2                 1

df$m <- ifelse(df$split_coefficient == 1,
               df$adjusted_close, 
               df$adjusted_close * df$split_coefficient
               )

# df
#    adjusted_close split_coefficient  m
# 1               5                 1  5
# 2               2                 2  4
# 3               3                 2  6
# 4               2                 2  4
# 5               4                 2  8
# 6               5                 2 10
# 7               1                 1  1
# 8               2                 1  2
# 9               2                 2  4
# 10              2                 1  2
```

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what OP wants, i.e. you should have `!=` not `==` in the condition.

Comment: Check the conditions evaluation. When it is `==` to 1, then it evaluates to `TRUE` and `ifelse` returns `df$adjusted_close`, otherwise, it evaluates to `FALSE` and returns `df$adjusted_close * df$split_coefficient`

Comment: Correct but for unclear reasons OP says he only wants to multiply when the value is 1.